# Detect Swipe Down on UITextView Scrolled to Top

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a `UITextView` occupying the entire screen. I want to move it when the user swipe down when the textview is scrolled to top.

Problem :

- I tried adding a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on the `textView`, but there're conflicts between the gesture recognizer and the scroll of the `textView`. It only works when there's not enough content in the `textView` to need a scroll (so when the `textView` is *static*)
- I tried using the `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` method but this method is not called when the `textView` is *static* (because there's nothing to scroll, makes sense). Also, in this method I don't know if the user scroll up or down

Is there a solution for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a solution.  You need to make sure your ViewController is the delegate for the UISwipeGestureRecognizer, then implement the method from the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.  There are several other methods in the protocol if you want to fine tune how you want the recognizers to compete with each other.

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Then you are just left with checking if you're at the top of the scrollView.

```
    @IBAction func SwipeDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        println("Swipe Down Detected")
        if textView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        println("And we were at (or above) the top of the text")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working? `SwipeDown` is not detected at all.